# How to generate presentation tables out of pandas data frames?

Tags: pandas

After exploring and analyzing data with `pandas` I often create summarize tables (e.g. "table 1"). Currently I use `pandas` to create (layout) such tables and then export them to Excel via `DataFrame.to_excel()`.

For example here you see in the first row the number of people and their mean age per group in the second row.

```
                GroupA   GroupB    Total
Total           959.00   764.00  1723.00
Age    Mean      73.34    73.55    73.43
```

Pandas dataframes are not suited to present data and offer layout options. I am aware of that. One problem for example is the `Total` row where the integers are converted to `float64` because I added the mean values in the next row and they are float.

How do you generate "presentation tables" out of pandas data frames?

Answer (score 2):

You can see the *prettytable* package. It has some simple API to convert *dataframe* into some good looking format.

https://pypi.org/project/prettytable/